# Could you damage a 2.5" HDD by grabbing it while spinning?

Tags: hard-drive

A few **seconds** ago the following happened to me.

I finished secure-erasing an old functioning SATA 2.5 inches hard drive using a USB adapter connected to my laptop. Instead of unplugging the USB first, because I need to wipe another drive, I unplugged the SATA side of the adpter, but as the disk was not screwed/attached to anything, I held it with my hand. One finger on the bottom and two on the top.

Of course, I used a bit of pressure to hold the disk firm while unplugging the cable.

**Then I heard it** just after the cable stopped supplying power. A scratching noise. I used enough physical strength so that the inside of the case touched the spinning plate. Not a loud scratch, no cracks, but indeed a scratch.

I'll probably start some surface test night-time. But... could this have damaged the drive?

Related: https://superuser.com/a/1645708/53108 (the heads were likely already parked)

Comment: "I used a bit of pressure to hold the disk firm while unplugging the cable."   It is difficult to tell if the pressure you described prevented the parking mechanism from operating. Hard disks are not designed for extra pressure on them. You should do the testing as you describe.

Comment: The only two things that could result in the scratching sound if there's no visible indent on the drive's casing is the top bearing plate screw or the top of the HSA arm. If it was the HSA arm and it bent even a minute amount, there's a high probability the top head is going to be out of spec _(if higher, read/write errors can occur, whereas if lower it'll scratch the top side of the top platter)_. Running a short and long S.MA.R.T test, then reviewing the S.M.A.R.T output, will confirm if the top head was bent lower as it'll result in a hardware error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could have damaged it, but it is entirely possible you did not. The drives are thin and the top and bottom metalwork thin and flexible enough that if you squeeze it then it could apply pressure to parts of the drive that were not designed for it.

It is entirely possible that the only part that made contact is the centre bearing of the drive and not the actual disk surface. In that case the drive may well be mostly fine, with some slight stress on the bearing. See the image below for an example drive, you may have only touched the centre area with the 8 concentric holes and not the surface. Only a full disk scan will tell for certain.

[image]

When pulling a drive out you should, out of preference, perform a "safe eject" from the operating system to park and power down the drive, or lacking that facility remove the power and let the drive spin down.

You should also avoid putting any force on the top or bottom (the largest surfaces) of the drive as the top surface is a thin piece of folded sheet metal that with moderate force is reasonably flexible.

Instead, you should use the sides of the drive to pull it out. The thin wall there has a lot of structural support from both the lid and base and will be a lot stronger and more rigid.

Comment: `you should use the sides of the drive to pull it out` ==> definitely

Comment: And I likely squeezed the central bearing.

Comment: In which case the drive surface *might* be okay and the worst is a slight scratch on the bearing and a bit more wear on it from the squeeze. Out of an abundance of paranoia I personally would do some testing, either test at random points across the drive such as https://hddscan.com/ or a full surface scan.